# How to pass the pointer of a memory buffer created by calloc to a sub function?

Tags: string, memory-management

Here is my code:
I have to dynamically create some memory for the string Str1 and pass its pointer to the other two functions in a recursive manner. The code compiles but when it enters Function2 it generates an exception saying that cannot write c[i], bad pointer? (i.e. it does not write to Str1)
What am i doing wrong?

```
void Function1(void)
{
    char *Str1;
    Str1 = calloc(25, sizeof(char));
    pFileIn  = fopen("in.txt", "r");
    pFileOut = fopen("out.txt", "w+");
    if (pFileIn==NULL) printf("Error opening file");
    else
    {
        while (Function2(pFileIn, Str1))
        {
            if (! Function3(pFileOut, Str1))
            {
              fseek(pFileOut, 0, SEEK_END);
              fprintf(pFileOut, "%s", Str1);
              rewind(pFileOut);
            }
        }
        fclose(pFileIn);
        fclose(pFileOut);
}

int Function2(FILE* f, char * c)
{
  int i=0;
  do
  {
      c[i] = fgetc(f);
     if (c[i]==EOF)
        return FALSE;
    } while (c[i++]!='\n');
  c[i] = '\0';
  return TRUE;
}
int Function3(FILE* f, char * c)
{
  char *Str2;
    Str2 = calloc(25, sizeof(char));
  while (Function2(f, Str2))
  {
    if (strcmp(c, Str2)==0)
      return TRUE;
  }

  rewind(f);
  return FALSE;
}
```

Comment: Can you guarantee that the input lines are 24 characters or shorter?  Your code will try to write into bad memory if your lines  are longer.

Comment: Try "getline". Or else you need to terminate your loop if it reaches max character.int Function2(FILE* f, char * c, int n_size)
{
  int i=0;
  do
  {
      c[i] = fgetc(f);
     if (c[i]==EOF)
        return FALSE;
    } while (c[i++]!='\n' && i < n_size);
  c[i] = '\0';
  return TRUE;
}